# Adding conditional to react, redux, and API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-forms

I was wondering how I can make updates to a form using React, Redux, and API. I want to add a conditional to my component. As in if, the page is in edit mode, I would like to change the page to edit mode and if it is not, render the page as it does normally.

I want the user to be able to make updates and save those changes to the backend.

```
class SingleCampus extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    const { User } = this.props;
    const hasTest = user.tests && user.tests.length;

return (
  <div>
    <div className="single-user">
      <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      <im`enter code here`g src={user.imageUrl} alt={user.name} />
      <h3>
        <b>Address:</b>
        {user.address}
      </h3>
      <b>Description:</b>
      <p> {user.description}</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
    {hasTest ? (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
         
          {user.tests.map((test) => {
            return (
              <span key={test.id}>
                <Link to={`/test/${test.id}`}>
                  <h3>
                    {test.grade} 
                  </h3>
                </Link>
         
              </span>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    ) : (
      <h2>There are no test for this user!</h2>
    )}
  </div>
  );
  }
}
const mapState = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  getUser: (id) => {
    dispatch(fetchSingleUser(id));
  },
});


`
```

Comment: What have you already tried to implement an "edit mode" for this component?

Comment: I tried to add a state value of edit and set it false. And added a button to toggle the state from true - false depending on the users request and depending on the state it would either display the edit-view or it would render the view-mode only. The confusion comes  with not knowing how to update my database. How and when exactly to call the thunk to dispatch the action and make the axios call. Would I need componentwillUpdate for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to do so is to add a variable to your state, (no matter local state or Redux state)
e.g.

```js
// I suppose this is your Redux state used to map state to props?
const mapState = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
  isDisabled: state.isDisabled,
});
```

change your text value in the component to text box, you may need to use some UI package such as Material UI.
Then, make it disabled depends on your isDisabled state value
also, on value change, you need to implement to dispatch the updated value.

```js
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
......
      <b>Description:</b>
      <p> {user.description}</p>
      <TextField
        value={user.description}
        onChange={handleChange}  // update description value and dispatch the user object
        InputProps={{
          readOnly: props.isDisabled,
        }}
      />
```

finally, add a button to change the isDisabled value if in read only mode, process save in  edit mode

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
......
      <Button 
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleEditSave}  // handle edit/save logic
      >{props.isDisabled ? `Edit` : `Save`}        
      </Button>
```